# PC is not starting properly

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, desktop-computer, cmos

I've changed the case on my pc and now if I plug in and power straight away the power light and fans start but then stop completely.

To get it to boot properly I carry out the following steps:

1. remove power cord
2. press and hold the power button down for 5-10 secs
3. put the power cord back in
4. press the power up button

After this the PC works fine.

Any ideas/help is appreciated?

Comment: What happens exactly when you attempt to start it up?

Comment: If i plug in and power straight away the power light and fans start but then stop completly. I then go through the process above and it will start.

Comment: This is based on what you've told me: when immediately plugging in power lead, I've always seen fans and lights spin up for a second or two. Waiting moments later to then press the power on button will result in a successful boot. Try waiting 5 seconds after plugging in power lead to press the power button. If problem persists, I'd question the health of your power supply.

Comment: I've waited in the past and nothing happens..........I'll look at the power supply.

Comment: I replaced the CR3032 battery - that was a cheap option and also replaced the power supply unit with a BeQuiet unit and now I have no problems!

Comment: On another note I also removed the graphics card I had for the machine - what a difference in noise there is - so much quieter! It's built-in fan is louder than a hairdryer!!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Which was the fix, the CMOS battery or PSU?